# Как добавить 2 свойства в переменную?

Tags: php

Имеется `$bot->sendInlineKeyboard($chat_id, $text, $keyboardCategory);`

нужно к `$bot->` добавить ещё одно свойсто `sendKeyboard` и чтобы `($chat_id, $text, $keyboardCategory);` было на оба свойства

Comment: то есть, что бы интерфейс вызова  был такой  `$bot->sendKeyboard($chat_id, $text, $keyboardCategory)->sendInlineKeyboard();` ?

Comment: нужна цепочка вызова?

Answer (score 0):

Вот образно. Что вам нужно, решайте сами. 
Есть объект $bot предположим что так же называется и класс bot.

```
    <?php 
class bot {

        /**
        * область видимости свойств объекта может быть public, private,  protected 
        */
        public $chat_id;
        public $text;
        public $keyboardCategory; // вот тут мы добавили свойство.

        public function __construct($chat_id, $text, $keyboardCategory ){
           $this->chat_id = $chat_id;
           $this->text = $text;
           $this->keyboardCategory =$keyboardCategory;
        }


        public function sendInlineKeyboard($chat_id, $text, $keyboardCategory  ){
        ... код 
        }

    // а вот тут мы добавили метод sendKeyboard
        public function sendKeyboard ($chat_id, $text, $keyboardCategory){
            ... код 
        }

    }

    ?>
```